# What kind of variable is $row from a mysql fetch?

Tags: php, mysql, row, fetch

I am growing extremely frustrated with this issue. I'm attempting to do a simple query but it won't work. It's extremely simple. I send an input via post and I've tested it already. The post variable is arriving in tact. The only issue is when I echo "$row['id']" i get a blank variable passed back to my html function every time. I created an alert for when i get 
the data back in my html file and it flashes a blank alert every time. Before arriving at this code I made the file echo "not found" if $row was empty and it was empty when I expected it to be. When it's not empty though, I can't use the variables stored in the associative array. Yes, "id" is absolutely there. I've checked the database and there is only one "classes" row for testing.

```
<?php
$tempClass = $_POST["class"];
$tempClassArray = explode("=",$tempClass);
$class = $tempClassArray[1];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","*****","*******");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM classes WHERE className LIKE '%$class%' OR                    
classNumber LIKE '%$class%' OR section LIKE '%$class%'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['id'];
}
```

?>

Comment: How Do I access the $row variable? Do i need to convert it to something before I can use it? ID is an integer.

Comment: if id is the first field in the table then use printf("printing id %d", $row[0]); else use different index like row[1], row[2] based on the position of field id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a `mysqli` query -

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, ....);
```

But trying to use a `mysql` (not `mysqli`) fetch

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

Try changing it to [`mysqli_fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo $row['id'];
}
```

it is common to accidentally mix up `mysql` and `mysqli` functions

Comment: That fixed it. I spent 6 hours changing code in order to find a missing "i". Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the $row variable first

```
print_r($row);
```

if it only print "array( )", then the query might have failed, you may try to echo it as well to see if there is any errors.

to answer the title, mysql_fetch_array Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead.

reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

ps: i think this should go to comment section, but since i dont have enough reputation,sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

try this though it works same as previous but can give a try

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 echo $row['id'];
}
```

Comment: I've tried that already. PHP is just determined to make me crazy today. Still an empty return.